# Why is a "self" reference required to call ajax from within a jQuery dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following jquery function opens a tutorial dialog if a specific pattern is detected. I recently added a "do not show again" checkbox, so the user can decide they don't want to see the popup anymore, which included an ajax call to set a session variable to store this setting. I had trouble getting the ajax call to work until I added a "this" reference. Does anyone know why the "this" is needed? #userDismiss should select the input with the corresponding ID, and I've confirmed that the ID is used nowhere else in the codebase for this project. The below code works, but I'm fairly new to jQuery and am interested in learning more about why it works as written.

jQuery code fragment:

```
$('#tutorial').dialog
({
    show: "fade",
    title: "Helpful Hint",
    modal: false,
    close: function(event, ui)
    {
        if ($('#userDismiss', this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax/do-not-show-again.php'
            });
        }
    },
    buttons:
    {
        Okay: function()
        {
                $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the php snippet containing the div used for the dialog in the above jquery code

```
    <div class="no-disp" $tutorial>
        <p>This is a tutorial message</p>
        <br />
        <input id="userDismiss" type="checkbox" name="dismiss">Don't show me this again</input>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `this` you mean is this `$('#userDismiss', this)` ?

Comment: The `this` in that statement provides context to the selector. It is the same as saying `$('#tutorial').find('#userDismiss');`

Comment: It's a scope selector similar to `$(this).find('#userDismiss')` but that wouldn't make any sense since ID's are supposed to be unique.

Comment: You're sure that you aren't duplicating the tutorial div at any point?  The only reason you should need to specify the scope on an ID selector is if there are multiple instances of that ID on the page.

Comment: There's only two possible causes. Either the id isn't unique, or the dialog has been detached from the DOM. Since the latter doesn't happen, the former is likely the cause. Are you creating the html for this dialog every time you open it? if so, are you deleting it after closing it?

Comment: The id is definitely unique in the codebase, and the html for this dialog is written into the page itself. There's a function not shown here that returns true if the pattern we're looking for is found. If the function returns true, the variable $tutorial is set to "id='tutorial", which allows jQuery to select it to create the dialog. As far as I know, that means the html is being created once per page view. @Kevin B, I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: A thought I had was that since the <input> being selected for the ajax call is not checked in the html, but is set to checked while the dialog window is open, it needs "this" to specify that the scope is the jquery dialog, not the HTML element. Does that make any sense?

Comment: nope, doesn't make any sense. the `.is(...` is somewhat irrelevant, the issue is `$('#userDismiss', this)` selects an element with `,this` but not without it (or, without it it is selecting the wrong element).

Answer (score -1):

Because you are doing someting "$(this).dialog('close');" or testing a condition over a element that is receiving a evenement "event"